# Read outside .Java file and extract the method details into Java code

Tags: java, file-read

I need to read a java project files from outside of that project. So Java Reflection cannot be used. Is there any mechanism or specific API to read a .java files of a project and extract the method signature details into a java code. Maybe a text search API ?

Comment: Is that java file to be read is in the same project and do you know the file path and full file name of that class(package+class name).

Comment: No, its not in the same project. Its actually a separate project file.

Comment: Is it Possible to copy that file at runtime, in your project or machine on which your program is reading. And then get the path of that File relative to your program/machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could still read it by providing the path to class file directory. And then you need to provide the exact package to the class file

```
File file = new File("Absolute_path\\target\\classes\\");
    URL urlList[] = {file.toURL()};
    URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urlList, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
    Class c = (Class) Class.forName("com.java.dto.BaseDTO", true, loader);
```

Thanks JTeam